# How can I deploy my MERN Stack application to Godaddy vps?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern, vps

Hi there I am new to mernstack development. I want to deploy my mern stack application to go daddy vps but through documentation I came to know GoDaddy cPanel doesn't support mongodb.Can any one help me with that. Thanks in advance